# How to autoload a class in ruby

Tags: ruby, autoload

I have a module as follows

-path of class MyClass lib/a/b/myclass.rb

```
module A
  module B
    class MyClass
      puts 'inside myclass'
    end
  end
end
```

Now i want to autoload the above class from a file in root directory.
File name : dostuff

```
def main
  autoload A::B:MyClass,'a/b/myclass.rb' #path is correct , getting error here
  c = A::B:MyClass.new
end

main
```

Am getting error:  `uninitialized constant A::B::MyClass (NameError)`

If i use require as follows and delete autoload code everything works fins.

```
require 'a/b/myclass'
```

Comment: Myclass or MyClass?

Comment: is `lib` in your LOAD_PATH?

Comment: ignore typos plz. if i load the module using require 'a/b/myclass' eveerything is working fine. But i want to use autoload for someother reason . lib is in my load path.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can u help me solve this?

Answer (score 4):

You're asking too much of the auto-loader. It can really only deal with one level at a time. That means you need this by expressing each module or class in a separate file:

```
# a.rb
module A
  autoload(:B, 'a/b')
end

# a/b.rb
module A::B
  autoload(:MyClass, 'a/b/my_class')
end

# a/b/my_class.rb
class A::B::MyClass
end
```

Then you can auto-load A:

```
autoload(:A, 'a')

A::B::MyClass.new
```

It's also highly unconventional to have a `main` function in Ruby. Normally you just put code at the top level in a context that is already called `main`.

Comment: :Thanks for answering. But why cant i autoload  A::B::MyClass from the main? Its kind of waste to create modules with just boilerplate autoload to next nested module. Any other work arounds?

Comment: It's because in your code you're referencing `A::B` which doesn't exist yet, so it blows up. Although this might seem like a mess, it's more conventional and makes organizing code easier. This is how people expect your library to be laid out on the filesystem.